# Contingency table with name of factors instead of counts

Tags: r, xtable

I have a dataframe with 3 columns. The first has the names of my categories, the second (q2) and the third (q3) columns contain other factors.
Es:

```
q1 q2 q3
A  w  y
G  x  x
F  y  z
```

I'm using

```
t1 <- xtabs(~q2+q3, data=db)
```

to create a contingency table and know how many combo categories there are.

How  I can obtain in the itersection cells the names of factors that're in column q1?

```
     x y z
   w 0 1 0
   x 1 0 0
   y 0 0 1
```

In the example, instead of 1, I want A, G or F.

Comment: Have you tried `dcast` i.e. `library(reshape2); dcast(df1, q2~q3, value.var="q1")`

Comment: It seems to work if it's only one factor per combination... Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

Comment: In that case, you need to add a sequence column grouped by the variables and then do `dcast`.  There are many dupes for this case as well.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to assign `q1` to `t1` using `q2` and `q3` as indices.

```
> dn <- lapply(db[2:3], levels)
> t1 <- array(NA, lengths(dn), dn)
> t1[cbind(db$q2, db$q3)] <- levels(db$q1)[db$q1]
> t1
   q3
q2  x   y   z  
  w NA  "A" NA 
  x "G" NA  NA 
  y NA  NA  "F"
```